# problem with accessing attributes of relationship after fetching with setPropertiesToFetch

Tags: iphone, core-data

I'm only fetching some attributes and a 1-to-1 relationship of an entity using -setPropertiesToFetch and result type set to NSDictionaryResultType. 
Now I have a problem accessing the attributes of the returned relationship. As soon as I want to access a property I get an NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Here is the full Exception:

```
2011-03-23 11:02:10.435 ThurboApp[32996:207] -[_NSObjectID_48_0 lon]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5a3f490
2011-03-23 11:02:10.441 ThurboApp[32996:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_NSObjectID_48_0 lon]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5a3f490'
```

Here is the corresponding source code:

```
    - (void)fetchAllPois
{
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"POI" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    request.entity = entity;
    [request setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];
    [request setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"poiId",@"categoryId",@"poiTitle",@"coordinates", nil]];
    request.sortDescriptors = nil;
    request.predicate = nil;

    NSError *error = nil;
    self.fetchResult = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

}


- (MapPoint *)createMapPointFromDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dict
{
    NSString *poiId = [dict objectForKey:@"poiId"];
    NSString *title = [dict objectForKey:@"poiTitle"];
    Coordinates *coords = (Coordinates *)[dict objectForKey:@"coordinates"];
    NSNumber *category = [dict objectForKey:@"categoryId"];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([coords.lat doubleValue], [coords.lon doubleValue]); //here raises the exception
    MapPoint *p = [[[MapPoint alloc] initWithPoiId:poiId title:title category:[category intValue] coordinates:coordinates] autorelease];
    return p;

}
```

interface for Coordinates:

```
@interface Coordinates :  NSManagedObject  
{
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * lat;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * alt;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * lon;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSManagedObject * poi;

@end
```

I've already checked, that the values returned in the dictionaries are correct. Even coordinates points to a Coordinate object.

Help is much appreciated.

Comment: So what was the selector that was sent? Providing the full exception information would be helpful.

Comment: @freespace lon and lat are sent to Coordinates

Comment: added the full exception description

Comment: Looks like it is a generic object receiving the selector, not `Coordinate` or even an `NSManagedObject` subclass. Add this after assignment to coords: if ([coords isKindOfClass:[Coordinates class]]) NSLog(@"is Coordinate instance"); See if that prints.

Comment: It doesn't, so there seems to be a mistake how I do it, but I can't figure out what it is...

Comment: Then just print out [coords class] and see what is being returned. Did you setup your CoreData classes properly? If not it won't know to return an Coords object.

Comment: It's this strange '_NSObjectID_48_0'. What do you mean by setting up my CoreData classes properly? When I fetch the whole Object everthing is fine, but in this case I want to only fetch some properties for performance reasons.

Comment: Does CoreData know that there is a corresponding Coordinates class for the Coordinates entity in your data model?

Comment: I don't know exactly what you mean. I have a Coordinates class which extends NSManagedObject and I'm using it all over the place in the app, as a relationship to a POI Entity and everything works fine. However in this particular case I'm only interested in the coordinates plus some other attributes from the POI entity for performance reasons. I could easily delete the Coordinates entity and include lon, lat and alt as attributes on the POI entity, but I'm wondering why this doesn't work, what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Does it work if you fetch all attributes? It is difficult to guess what might be wrong b/c CoreData goes beyond just code snippets. The settings in your xcdatamodeld matters too.

Comment: yeah it works when I fetch everything and resultType is set to object. Even the attributes work with the way I'm doing it here. The only problem is the relationship.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok I managed to solve the problem. What you get for the relationship is a NSManagedObjectID which you can use with objectWithID to get the Entity itself. 
Here is the updated code:

```
- (MapPoint *)createMapPointFromDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dict
{
    NSString *poiId = [dict objectForKey:@"poiId"];
    NSString *title = [dict objectForKey:@"poiTitle"];
    NSManagedObjectID *coordsID = (NSManagedObjectID *)[dict objectForKey:@"coordinates"]; //get the objectid
    NSNumber *category = [dict objectForKey:@"categoryId"];
    Coordinates *coords = (Coordinates *)[self.managedObjectContext objectWithID:coordsID]; //get the actual managedobject
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([coords.lat doubleValue], [coords.lon doubleValue]);
    MapPoint *p = [[[MapPoint alloc] initWithPoiId:poiId title:title category:category coordinates:coordinates] autorelease];
    return p;

}
```